# Use styled-components to center React Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Is it possible to use `styled-component` to create a wrapper container containing React Bootstrap's `Modal` component in order to make the modal be both horizontally and vertically aligned?

Tried creating `CenteredModal` container as shown, but the `.modal` element does not appear to have the new styles applied to it.

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CenteredModal = styled.div`
    & .modal {
        display: flex !important;
        align-items: center;
    }
`

interface MyModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean,
    onHide: () => void
}

export default function MyModal({
    isOpen = false,
    onHide,
}: MyModalProps) {
    return (
        <CenteredModal>
            <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={onHide}>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </Modal>
        </CenteredModal>
    )
}
```

Comment: Model uses position fixed, so it won't affect by surrounding components.

Answer (score 2):

Because Modal of react-bootstrap isn't render inside CenteredModal, so your style can't affect it (You can open the browser developer tool to see, it should be rendered at the bottom of the html body not in the CenteredModal div element).

I saw react-bootstrap is already provides a centering method, is this what you want? you can take a look https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Answer (score 2):

why not use `centered` prop ?
example :

```
<Modal
  size="lg"
  centered
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new container just needs a little tweaking:

```
const CenteredModal = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CenteredModal = styled(Modal)`
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
`;
```